# How to auto register a class when it's defined

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, decorator, metaclass

I want to have an instance of class registered when the class is defined.  Ideally the code below would do the trick.

```
registry = {}

def register( cls ):
   registry[cls.__name__] = cls() #problem here
   return cls

@register
class MyClass( Base ):
   def __init__(self):
      super( MyClass, self ).__init__()
```

Unfortunately, this code generates the error `NameError: global name 'MyClass' is not defined`.

What's going on is at the `#problem here` line I'm trying to instantiate a `MyClass` but the decorator hasn't returned yet so it doesn't exist.

Is the someway around this using metaclasses or something?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Yes, meta classes can do this.  A meta class' `__new__` method returns the class, so just register that class before returning it.

```
class MetaClass(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, attrs):
        newclass = super(MetaClass, cls).__new__(cls, clsname, bases, attrs)
        register(newclass)  # here is your register function
        return newclass

class MyClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaClass
```

The previous example works in Python 2.x.  In Python 3.x, the definition of `MyClass` is slightly different (while `MetaClass` is not shown because it is unchanged - except that `super(MetaClass, cls)` can become `super()` if you want):

```
#Python 3.x

class MyClass(metaclass=MetaClass):
    pass
```

As of Python 3.6 there is also a new `__init_subclass__` method (see [PEP 487](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0487)) that can be used instead of a meta class (thanks to @matusko for his answer below):

```
class ParentClass:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        register(cls)

class MyClass(ParentClass):
    pass
```

[edit: fixed missing `cls` argument to `super().__new__()`]

[edit: added Python 3.x example]

[edit: corrected order of args to super(), and improved description of 3.x differences]

[edit: add Python 3.6 `__init_subclass__` example]

Comment: btw, here is a real world example of code that does exactly this (this is not my code, but I've used the library a lot).  Look at lines 67-90 (as of my writing this).  https://github.com/ask/celery/blob/master/celery/task/base.py

Comment: @dappawit: Celery appears to not be using this technique now. However, it worked really well for me!

Comment: Indeed, you can even do this in a base class, and it will affect any subclasses you create, too.

Comment: @Matthew: Celery still uses this technique, it's just located in a different file: https://github.com/ask/celery/blob/master/celery/app/task.py (lines 95-157 as of my writing this)

Comment: @deft_code: Using a metaclass `__new__` actually doesn't help, it only appears to because you've left out the `super` call. See my answer for (far too much) more explanation.

Comment: @Ben: Perhaps I am missing something, but I don't see the problem with the metaclass solution in regards to using ``super``.  I see why removing the super call would solve the OPs problem, but I don't see why that is still an issue in my solution.  Using metaclasses in this way, the  ``__init__`` method is never called during class registration because we register the class object, not a class instance.  Thus, using ``super()`` in ``MyClass.__init__`` (and/or a subclass thereof) works as expected.

Comment: @Ben: Ignore my comment above, I didn't see that the OP was creating an instance of the class in his register function.  Of course, that won't work.  I think one would be well advised to *not* construct a instance of the class in this situation (as you suggest in your post).  One more thing: I think a nice thing about the metaclass approach is that all subclasses will also be registered.  With a decorator, you'd have to apply it to each subclass individually.  But as always, there's many ways to do it--it depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Why not register the class instance in the metaclass's `__init__()`? The instance is created by that time and you can simply register it as `register(cls)`, where `cls` is `__init__()`'s first argument.

Comment: Fixed (and permenent) link for @dappawit's comment: https://github.com/ask/celery/blob/6b91c7e0f2d9d1c1f16899161977ae0c2662f9fd/celery/task/base.py#L64

Comment: What if the parent is constructed with `metaclass=ABCMeta`? Can we have multiple metaclasses?

Answer (score 57):

## Since python 3.6 you don't need metaclasses to solve this

In python 3.6 simpler customization of class creation was introduced ([PEP 487](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0487)).

> An `__init_subclass__` hook that initializes all subclasses of a given class.

Proposal includes following example of [subclass registration](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0487/#subclass-registration)

```
class PluginBase:
    subclasses = []

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.subclasses.append(cls)
```

> In this example, `PluginBase.subclasses` will contain a plain list of
>   all subclasses in the entire inheritance tree. One should note that
>   this also works nicely as a mixin class.

Comment: Does this require the subclass to be instantiated or will it register when the subclass has been defined.  I tried using the code and it seems to be the former although it's the latter that is being requested.

Comment: It will register on subclass definition. Make sure that module with subclass was imported.

Comment: @matusko, forgive, my asking, but imported where. I have implemented a similar issue but my registry (subclasses) is empty.

Comment: If you define your subclass in another module (file), python will only read the defunition and register the subclass after you import that module somewhere in your program. Same applies to single module, if you ask for PluginBase.subclasses before defining a subclass, it will be empty.

Answer (score 14):

The problem isn't actually caused by the line you've indicated, but by the `super` call in the `__init__` method. The problem remains if you use a metaclass as suggested by dappawit; the reason the example from that answer works is simply that dappawit has simplified your example by omitting the `Base` class and therefore the `super` call. In the following example, neither `ClassWithMeta` nor `DecoratedClass` work:

```
registry = {}
def register(cls):
    registry[cls.__name__] = cls()
    return cls

class MetaClass(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, attrs):
        newclass = super(cls, MetaClass).__new__(cls, clsname, bases, attrs)
        register(newclass)  # here is your register function
        return newclass

class Base(object):
    pass


class ClassWithMeta(Base):
    __metaclass__ = MetaClass

    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassWithMeta, self).__init__()


@register
class DecoratedClass(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DecoratedClass, self).__init__()
```

The problem is the same in both cases; the `register` function is called (either by the metaclass or directly as a decorator) after the **class object** is created, but before it has been bound to a name. This is where `super` gets gnarly (in Python 2.x), because it requires you to refer to the class in the `super` call, which you can only reasonably do by using the global name and trusting that it will have been bound to that name by the time the `super` call is invoked. In this case, that trust is misplaced.

I think a metaclass is the wrong solution here. Metaclasses are for making a family of *classes* that have some custom behaviour in common, exactly as classes are for making a family of instances that have some custom behavior in common. All you're doing is calling a function on a class. You wouldn't define a class to call a function on a string, neither should you define a metaclass to call a function on a class.

So, the problem is a fundamental incompatibility between: (1) using hooks in the class creation process to create instances of the class, and (2) using `super`.

One way to resolve this is to not use `super`. `super` solves a hard problem, but it introduces others (this is one of them). If you're using a complex multiple inheritance scheme, `super`'s problems are better than the problems of not using `super`, and if you're inheriting from third-party classes that use `super` then you have to use `super`. If neither of those conditions are true, then just replacing your `super` calls with direct base class calls may actually be a reasonable solution.

Another way is to not hook `register` into class creation. Adding `register(MyClass)` after each of your class definitions is pretty equivalent to adding `@register` before them or `__metaclass__ = Registered` (or whatever you call the metaclass) into them. A line down the bottom is much less self-documenting than a nice declaration up the top of the class though, so this doesn't feel great, but again it may actually be a reasonable solution.

Finally, you can turn to hacks that are unpleasant, but will probably work. The problem is that a name is being looked up in a module's global scope *just before* it's been bound there. So you could cheat, as follows:

```
def register(cls):
    name = cls.__name__
    force_bound = False
    if '__init__' in cls.__dict__:
        cls.__init__.func_globals[name] = cls
        force_bound = True
    try:
        registry[name] = cls()
    finally:
        if force_bound:
            del cls.__init__.func_globals[name]
    return cls
```

Here's how this works:

1. We first check to see whether `__init__` is in `cls.__dict__` (as opposed to whether it has an `__init__` attribute, which will always be true). If it's inherited an `__init__` method from another class we're probably fine (because the superclass **will** already be bound to its name in the usual way), and the magic we're about to do doesn't work on `object.__init__` so we want to avoid trying that if the class is using a default `__init__`.
2. We lookup the `__init__` method and grab it's `func_globals` dictionary, which is where global lookups (such as to find the class referred to in a `super` call) will go. This is normally the global dictionary of the module where the `__init__` method was originally defined. Such a dictionary is *about* to have the `cls.__name__` inserted into it as soon as `register` returns, so we just insert it ourselves early.
3. We finally create an instance and insert it into the registry. This is in a try/finally block to make sure we remove the binding we created whether or not creating an instance throws an exception; this is very unlikely to be necessary (since 99.999% of the time the name is about to be rebound anyway), but it's best to keep weird magic like this as insulated as possible to minimise the chance that someday some other weird magic interacts badly with it.

This version of `register` will work whether it's invoked as a decorator or by the metaclass (which I still think is not a good use of a metaclass). There are some obscure cases where it will fail though:

1. I can imagine a weird class that *doesn't* have an `__init__` method but inherits one that calls `self.someMethod`, and `someMethod` is overridden in the class being defined and makes a `super` call. Probably unlikely.
2. The `__init__` method might have been defined in another module originally and then used in the class by doing `__init__ = externally_defined_function` in the class block. The `func_globals` attribute of the other module though, which means our temporary binding would clobber any definition of this class' name in that module (oops). Again, unlikely.
3. Probably other weird cases I haven't thought of.

You could try to add more hacks to make it a little more robust in these situations, but the nature of Python is both that these kind of hacks are possible and that it's impossible to make them absolutely bullet proof.

Answer (score 3):

The answers here didn't work for me in **python3**, because `__metaclass__` didn't work.

Here's my code registering all subclasses of a class at their definition time:

```
registered_models = set()

class RegisteredModel(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, superclasses, attributedict):
        newclass = type.__new__(cls, clsname, superclasses, attributedict)
        # condition to prevent base class registration
        if superclasses:
            registered_models.add(newclass)
        return newclass

class CustomDBModel(metaclass=RegisteredModel):
    pass

class BlogpostModel(CustomDBModel):
    pass

class CommentModel(CustomDBModel):
   pass

# prints out {<class '__main__.BlogpostModel'>, <class '__main__.CommentModel'>}
print(registered_models)
```

Comment: The syntax for specifying a metaclass changed in a trivial way between Python 2 & 3, so converting from one to the other is quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the Base class directly should work (instead of using super()):

```
  def __init__(self):
        Base.__init__(self)
```

Comment: I up-voted because this is actually (kind of) a right answer, and doesn't deserve 3 downvotes. There's no explanation though, so I wouldn't have voted for this answer if it was on 0.

Comment: Indeed: Base.__init__(self) is the simplest solution.

Comment: This needs explanation, took me a minute to realise why this was useful.

Answer (score 0):

It can be also done with something like this (without a registry function)

```py
_registry = {}

class MetaClass(type):
    def __init__(cls, clsname, bases, methods):
        super().__init__(clsname, bases, methods)
        _registry[cls.__name__] = cls


class MyClass1(metaclass=MetaClass): pass
class MyClass2(metaclass=MetaClass): pass

print(_registry)
# {'MyClass1': <class '__main__.MyClass1'>, 'MyClass2': <class '__main__.MyClass2'>}
```

Additionally, if we need to use a base abstract class (e.g. `Base()` class), we can do it this way (notice the metacalss inherits from `ABCMeta` instead of `type`)

```py
from abc import ABCMeta

_registry = {}

class MetaClass(ABCMeta):
    def __init__(cls, clsname, bases, methods):
        super().__init__(clsname, bases, methods)
        _registry[cls.__name__] = cls

class Base(metaclass=MetaClass): pass
class MyClass1(Base): pass
class MyClass2(Base): pass

print(_registry)
# {'Base': <class '__main__.Base'>, 'MyClass1': <class '__main__.MyClass1'>, 'MyClass2': <class '__main__.MyClass2'>}
```