# Length of list returns length of list name

Tags: python-3.x

```
Import random

set_list_1 = ["one"]
set_list_2 = ["two"]

number = random.choice(range(1, 3))

chosen_list = "set_list_" + str(number)

print(len(chosen_list))
```

Returns 10 instead of 1

How do i get it to return the length of the list instead of the length of the lists name?

Comment: here you go : https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea. You should use lists.

Try this;

```
Import random

set_list = [[], ["one"], ["two"]]
number = random.choice(range(1, 3))

chosen_list = set_list[number]
print(len(chosen_list))
```

If you absolutely want to access variables dynamically;

```
Import random

set_list_1 = ["one"]
set_list_2 = ["two"]

number = random.choice(range(1, 3))

chosen_list = eval("set_list_" + str(number))
print(len(chosen_list))
```

Comment: I was just using those lists as an example, i have more items in each list

Comment: You can append to lists as many as you want. If you want to do it as shown in the question, check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question per se, `chosen_list` isn't the list, but a string. So then `len()` returns the length of a string, that is to say, the number of characters in it.

**If you want to access the list instead by it's name :**

As stated by the other answer and the comment, you could first use `eval` for this.

You can also use the `locals()` (or maybe `globals()` if your lists are in the global scope) (depending on your current scope) dictionnary to avoid `eval`. These functions return a dictionnary containing everything you can access in the global (well the module scope to be accurate) / local scope.

```
import random

set_list_1 = ["one"]
set_list_2 = ["two"]

number = random.choice(range(1, 3))
chosen_list = locals()["set_list_" + str(number)]
print(len(chosen_list))
```

It's probably faster and safer than `eval`.

Or, you can register your lists in a `dict`, mapping the variable name to the `̀list`. For instance, you can do something like this :

```
import random
registry = {}

registry["set_list_1"] = ["one"]
registry["set_list_2"] = ["two"]
number = random.choice(range(1, 3))
chosen_list = registry["set_list_" + str(number)]
print(len(chosen_list))
```

This is without a doubt even faster than using `locals()`, and is actually a common pattern in python. [Here is a classic example of this, involving metaclasses.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189232/how-to-auto-register-a-class-when-its-defined)

Also, you can do this if you don't actually need the variables names for any other reason :

```
import random
registry = []

registry.append(["one"])
registry.append(["two"])
chosen_list = random.choice(registry)
print(len(chosen_list))
```