# How to register classes that inherit from an abstract class in python

Tags: python, factory-pattern, metaclass

I'm creating a module with a function that works as a factory of the implemented classes. It works registering the classes with the help of a metaclass (a pattern I have just copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189232/how-to-auto-register-a-class-when-its-defined)).

```
  _registry = {}
  
  def register_class(cls):
      _registry[cls.__name__] = cls
  
  
  class Meta(type):
      def __new__(meta, name, bases, class_dict):
          cls = type.__new__(meta, name, bases, class_dict)
          register_class(cls)
          return cls
  
  def factory(name):
          return _registry[name]()
```

This works so far.

Now a particularity I have is that I'm implementing classes that share a lot of functionality, therefore I define an abstract base class that implements most of the shared logic, and a large number of derived classes that refine certain particularities. The problem is that this leads to a metaclass conflict, as the metaclass of the the derived classes is both `ABCmeta` and `Meta`:

```
  from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
  
  _registry = {}
  
  def register_class(cls):
      _registry[cls.__name__] = cls
  
  
  class Meta(type):
      def __new__(meta, name, bases, class_dict):
          cls = type.__new__(meta, name, bases, class_dict)
          register_class(cls)
          return cls
  
  def factory(name):
          return _registry[name]()
  
  class Base(ABC):
      pass
  
  class Derived1(Base, metaclass=Meta):
      pass

  TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

How can I work around this conflict?

Comment: I don't normally use any of this stuff, because I don't like the formality or find it useful. However, instead of using a `Base` inherited from `ABC`, I think it works to just have `Meta` inherit from `ABCMeta` (making use of `super()` appropriately. Alternately, did you consider just using a decorator to do the registration? Obviously it's an extra line per class, but that replaces a `metaclass=` argument, and I think it's arguably more explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply combine the metaclasses you need into a suitable, derived, metaclass, and use that one as your metaclass. In this case, jsut derive your metaclass from "ABCMeta" instead of type:

```py
from abc import ABCMeta

  class Meta(ABCMeta):
      def __new__(meta, name, bases, class_dict):
          cls = super().__new__(meta, name, bases, class_dict)
          register_class(cls)
          return cls
```

Note the importance of using `super().__new__` instead of `type.__new__` - that is the requisite for our metaclass to be able to be combined with other metaclasses (as far as none of them interfere directly in the same attributes/logic your own metaclass is working on).

So, if you'd need *some* of your classes to use ABCMeta, and some that would use your metaclass alon, you could, just by replacing the call to `type.__new__`  with `super().__new__` use your metaclass as a mixin, to combine the ABCMeta as needed:

```
from abc import ABCMeta


class Meta(type):
   ...

class MetaWithAbc(Meta, ABCMeta):
    pass

class Base(metaclass=MetaWithAbc):
    pass

...
```

Also, since Python 3.6, the need for metaclasses has reduced considerably with the introduction of the special `__init_subclass__` method.
To simply add a class to  registry, as in this case, there is no need for a custom metaclass, if you have a common baseclass: `__init_subclass__` is called once per subclass, as it is created:

```
  from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
  
  _registry = {}
  
  def register_class(cls):
      _registry[cls.__name__] = cls
  
  def factory(name):
          return _registry[name]()
  
  class Base(ABC):
      def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
          # always make it colaborative:
          super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
          register_class(cls)
  
  
  class Derived1(Base):
      pass
```